# How can i generate hmacsha512 in Node Js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

```
var crypto = require('crypto');   
var output = encrypt(key,str); 
function encrypt(key, str){    
  var hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha512", key);   
  var signed = hmac.update(new Buffer(str, 'utf-8')).digest("base64");
  return signed
}
```

Here i am not getting proper output as same ouput in

```
Java.byte[] decodedKey =  Hex.decodeHesecretKey.toCharArray());
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, algorithm);
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);    
mac.init(keySpec);
```

Comment: Sir... When i am trying to Generate the hmac512 hash , the output is different from Java output.... In Node Js Output : OkT/UUvw9ROO3wRlJ/WA+xI/jhfkvh/fE9z3RdqoJqDpbrEIi8pXpNYiNKRywfpMgWgpn8xPz+A5/eUCdEr1UA==
In Java with same parameters 
Output  is diffferent

Comment: @Jonas W Sir ... This the java code for generating checksum.. 
String data = "jdhddhdhd";
byte[] decodedKey = Hex.decodeHesecretKey.toCharArray());
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, algorithm);
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
mac.init(keySpec);
byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] signatureBytes = mac.doFinal(dataBytes);
String signature = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(signatureBytes),"UTF-8");
return signature;